# Stuck in Android Studio after new project wizard

Tags: android-studio

After a lot of time with Eclipse + ADT, I decided to try Android Studio.
I work on a Windows 7 64bits machine, with JDK 7 64bits installed on it.

I've downloaded Android Studio 0.3.2, installed it, upgraded to 0.4.0, then tried to create a new blank project (targeting API 19). I clicked "Finish" on the wizard.

Android Studio seems to have downloaded Gradle successfully in C:/Users/me/.gradle (~150MB), then I get a progress dialog saying "Gradle: Build".

No more network activity, nothing even if I wait for 1h.

I've googled this problem, but found nothing comparable (only Gradle download problem, which doesn't seem to be my case).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of launching Android Studio with studio64.exe, I used studio.exe (32 bits version) and it works.

I have no idea why...

Comment: I have the same problem... (using studio.exe is the only option i have, win7 32bit)
any new insights?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Android Studio.
2. Navigate to "Configure-->Settings-->Graddle"
3. Check "Offline Work" option.
4. Back to main wizard screen.
5. Create your project.
6. Close your project (not the IDE).
7. Go to menu "File-->Settings...-->Graddle"
8. Uncheck "Offline Work" option.
9. Re-open your recent project.

It will try to download again some files... but at least you can test the IDE.