# Android Studio lags when creating project

Tags: android, android-studio

After installing Android Studio *141.2178183*-window, when I try to create a new project, after I get through all the menus, I get stuck at a screen with a progress bar that says "**Initializing Phone and Tablet**".
 No errors, no progress bar movement, literally nothing except the process eating up more and more memory.So i killed the task from the task manager.

[image]

As you can see, i choosed "*Import an Android Code sample*" from the main menu and i downloaed the ActionBar.... project. This project Opens with all the gradles builded.*So i can work with it* with no problem. But when i try to create a new one i have this problem ....

Beacause of the "Phone and tablet" reference, i downloaded all the Virtual Systems for API 23 but no enhancement.

I post the SDK pictures ...

### [image]

SDK Tools
[image]

*Do you have any idea what is going on ?!?*

Comment: just out of curiosity, which OS ?

Comment: How long did you leave the program before end tasking android studio?

Comment: Perhaps you are running into the [32-bit vs. 64-bit mystery problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789048/stuck-in-android-studio-after-new-project-wizard?rq=1).

Comment: Windows 7 OS @penta  and i left it about 3 minutes .

Comment: ok, since it is windows it can take long time....just have your pc connected to internet

Comment: @PaulRatazzi  I have x64 OS and i have no problem with Eclipse / java with my JDK and his own SDK.

Comment: **No solution with waiting ...**